# Does selenium or other web scraper tools are mandatory for scraping data from chrome to python script

Tags: python, google-chrome, web-scraping

So I wanted to scrape an website data. I have used selenium in my python script to scrape the data. But i have noticed that in Network section of Google Chrome Inspect, the chrome can record the XmlHttpRequest to find out the json/xml file of websites. So i was wondering that can i directly use this data in my python script as selenium is quite heavy weight and needs more bandwidth. Does selenium or other web scraper tools should be used as a medium to communicate with browser? If not, please give out some information about scraping data to be used for my python file only by using chrome itself.

Comment: This question gets asked a lot here and the consensus is that you should switch to puppeteer

Answer (score 0):

Definitely! Check out the `requests` module.
From there you can access the page source, and using data from it you can access the different aspects separately. Here are the things to consider though:
**Pros:**

- Faster, less to download. For things like AJAX requests, is extremely more efficient.
- Does not require graphic UI like selenium
- More precise; Get exactly what you need
- The ability to set Headers/Cookies/etc before making requests
- Images may be downloaded separately, with no obligation to download any of them.
- Allows as many sessions as you want to be opened in parallel, each
  can have different options(proxies, no cookies, consistent cookies,
  custom headers, block redirects, etc) without affecting the other.

**Cons:**

- Much harder to get into as opposed to `Selenium`, requires
  minimal knowledge of HTML's `GET` and `POST` , and a library
  like `re` or `BeautifulSoup` to extract data.
- For pages with javascript-generated data, depending how the
  javascript is implemented(or obfuscated), while always possible,
  could be extremely difficult to extract wanted data.

---

**Conclusion:**
I suggest you definitely learn `requests`, and use it for most cases; However if the javascript gets too complicated, then switch to selenium for an easier solution.  Look for some tutorials online, and then check the [official page](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) for an overview of what you've learned.